# How do I convert an AAC audio mp4 to mp3 using gstreamer

Tags: linux, gstreamer, audio-recording, lame

I want to take the AAC audio track from a mp4 container and encode it as a constant rate mp3 to play on some of my older audio equipment that can't play mp4s or variable bit rate mp3's.  I can't seem to get the pipeline right, it always comes out variable rate.  Also, is there a better way to be doing this?  Here's what I have.

```
gst-launch filesrc location=/path/to/file.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux \
demux. ! queue ! faad ! lamemp3enc quality=2 bitrate=192 cbr=true \
! id3v2mux ! filesink location=/path/to/file.mp3
```

Comment: If you still can't get `gstreamer` to work correctly, you might also try `ffmpeg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit rate doesn't take effect unless you specify a target. You should add **target=bitrate** to your pipeline.

```
gst-launch filesrc location=/path/to/file.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux \
demux. ! queue ! faad ! lamemp3enc quality=2 target=bitrate bitrate=192 cbr=true \
! id3v2mux ! filesink location=/path/to/file.mp3
```